# Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length $n$ that do not contain the substring $01$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So, I have solved the problem with consecutive zeros and ones and many other combinations, but this one I couldn't.

They left a hint that I could use the complement, but I have no idea where it comes into play here. I assume when I want to calculate the opposite of the instance when $0$ is followed by a $2$, because that's the problematic one.

Comment: Just to be clear, you mean that $01$ can not occur, right?  Or do you mean $0101$?

Comment: Assuming the former, what can a good string end in?  if it ends in $2$ then cutting off the $2$ leaves a generic good string.  If it ends in $0$ then cutting off the $0$ leaves a generic good string.  If it ends in $1$ then it must end in $11$ or $21$ so cutting off whichever of those two blocks leaves a generic good string.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What exactly do you mean by "consecutive 01"?

Comment: I mean that throughout the string there can't be a zero followed by 1

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $A_n$ the number of admissible strings and by $O_n$ the number of admissible strings ending with $0$. Then $A_n=3A_{n-1}-O_{n-1}$, since you may append any of three digits to an admissible string of length  $n-1$, unless this string ends in $0$, in which case you may only append $0$ or $2$. Furthermore $O_{n-1}=A_{n-2}$ since you may append a $0$ to any admissible string. It follows that the recursion you are after is
$$A_n-3A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}=0\qquad(n\geq3)\ .$$

Comment: Note that that $A_0=1$ and $A_1=3$, so $A_n=F_{2n+2}$, the even Fibonacci numbers. To see this bijectively, note that $F_{n+2}$ counts the number of binary strings of length $n$ with no two consecutive $1$'s. Given a binary string of length $2n$, partition it into $n$ consecutive substrings of length $2$. Then each such substring is one of $00$, $01$, $10$, and $01$ cannot be followed by $10$. Now map $01\mapsto 0$, $10\mapsto 1$, $00\mapsto 2$.